# Did Madhwas squat on an ancient Siva temple at Kudupu?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, temple

From a user review from [here](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g297630-d4138639-r398471820-Kudupu_Sri_Anantha_Padmanabha_Temple-Mangalore_Dakshina_Kannada_District_Karnata.html)

> As per historical inscription dated 1679 this is one of the Shiva Temple dedicated to lord shiva. The inscription captures that Chouta Queen Rani Chennamma during her elder sisters death given a land to the temple. Here lord shiva is worshiped as Anantheshwara. But Now the temple is called as Ananathapadhbhanabha (Vishnu) Temple by Madhwa Brahmins